# Workaround for adding aria-labelledby to nested elements in a table

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers, wai-aria

I have a table with nested forms, drop-downs, etc that I am trying to make accessible by making the screen reader read the column heading for each element in the column. currently, I am trying to add aria-labelledby with the id of the header, but that sometimes gets a bit tedious as the elements are created dynamically. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the scope attribute on your table's headers? That will associate your column headings with the table cells below them - and doesn't have to be applied each time you dynamically add content to the table.

See this page for an example:
http://www.hhs.gov/web/policies/webstandards/htmltable.html

Comment: That doesnt always work when the focus node when tabbing into the TD is a nested item. Especially in IE. anyways, I figured it out already. thanks